# Tomcat KeyStore Environment Path

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

We have the following example:

```
< Connector 
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

How can I make the "keystoreFile" point to an environment variable? ${env.CATALINA_HOME}/conf/file.jks doesn't works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is 3 years old....but i ran into the same problem today. So what I found out: tomcat searches the catalina_home as default, so you would just have to say
`keystoreFile="conf/file.jks"`
and it will find the keystore at 
`${env.CATALINA_HOME}/conf/file.jks`

Edit:
When Starting Tomcat from eclipse this does not work, because the CATALINA_HOME environment variable changes!

Answer (score 2):

If what you actually want is the value of CATALINA_HOME, there is also a system property ${catalina.home} that you can use.